# Using TNS Alias with ojdbc 12.1

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc, oracle12c, ucp

I am delevoping a java application that needs to access an Oracle Database. So far I have used the ojdbc6 driver without any problems. Now we are switching the databases to Oracle 12c so I wanted to use the newer JDBC driver.

This is the code

```
public class jdbctest {  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
  final PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();  
  oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.main(args);  
  System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "c:/Windows/System32/oracle-home/network/admin");  
  pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");  
  pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNSALIASWITHOUTDOTS");  
  System.out.println("Opening connection...");  
  final Connection connection = pds.getConnection();  
  System.out.println("Connection opened");  
  }  
}
```

This is the tnsnames.ora (HOST changed, because it is something in our intranet)

```
TNSALIAS.WITH.DOTS  = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = testdomain.de) (PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = EDISW) ))  
TNSALIASWITHOUTDOTS  = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = testdomain.de) (PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = EDISW) ))
```

This is the output for all four variations (2 drivers, 2 tnsaliases)
jdbc 11.2, TNSALIASWITHOUTDOTS

```
Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Fri_Aug_26_08:19:15_PDT_2011  
#Default Connection Properties Resource  
#Mon Apr 14 09:25:15 CEST 2014  
Opening connection...  
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exception beim Abrufen der Connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:488)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:163)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1055)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)  
  at jdbctest.main(jdbctest.java:18)  
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:368)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:49)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:80)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:102)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.createOnePooledConnectionInternal(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1776)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.access$600(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1612)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.createOnePooledConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:588)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.createOnePooledConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:170)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:354)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:167)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:148)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:166)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:1441)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1043)  
  ... 3 more
```

jdbc 11.2 TNSALIAS.WITH.DOTS

```
Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Fri_Aug_26_08:19:15_PDT_2011  
#Default Connection Properties Resource  
#Mon Apr 14 09:27:50 CEST 2014  
Opening connection...  
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exception beim Abrufen der Connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:488)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:163)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1055)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)  
  at jdbctest.main(jdbctest.java:18)  
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:368)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:49)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:80)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:102)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.createOnePooledConnectionInternal(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1776)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.access$600(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1612)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.createOnePooledConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:588)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.createOnePooledConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:170)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:354)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:167)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:148)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:166)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:1441)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1043)  
  ... 3 more
```

jdbc 12.1 TNSALIASWITHOUTDOTS

```
Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Thu_Apr_04_15:09:24_PDT_2013  
#Default Connection Properties Resource  
#Mon Apr 14 09:30:42 CEST 2014  
Opening connection...  
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exception beim Abrufen der Connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:488)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:163)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1055)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)  
  at jdbctest.main(jdbctest.java:18)  
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Benutzername/Kennwort ungültig; Anmeldung abgelehnt  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:368)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:49)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:80)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:102)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.createOnePooledConnectionInternal(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1776)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.access$600(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1612)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.createOnePooledConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:588)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.createOnePooledConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:170)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:354)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:167)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:148)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:166)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:1441)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1043)  
  ... 3 more
```

jdbc 12.1 TNSALIAS.WITH.DOTS

```
Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Thu_Apr_04_15:09:24_PDT_2013  
#Default Connection Properties Resource  
#Mon Apr 14 09:31:46 CEST 2014  
Opening connection...  
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exception beim Abrufen der Connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"   
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:488)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:163)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1055)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:966)  
  at jdbctest.main(jdbctest.java:18)  
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Connection kann nicht aus Datenquelle abgerufen werden: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"   
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:368)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:49)  
  at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:80)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:102)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(OracleDataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.createOnePooledConnectionInternal(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1776)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl$UniversalConnectionPoolInternal.access$600(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:1612)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.createOnePooledConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:588)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.createOnePooledConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:170)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:354)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:167)  
  at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:148)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:166)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:1441)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:82)  
  at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1043)  
  ... 3 more
```

For those who don't know german, ORA-01017 means "invalid username/password"

This means every combination except 12.1 with dots in TNS Alias is able to connect to the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are logging some information, however you never posted these log files and how is the tns names alias defined that is used in setURL command. In additon it might be helpful to have a look at the listener log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found out this is a bug in ojdbc driver 11.2.0.4 and onwards. We will create a bugreport at oracle.

workaround would be to use tnsaliases without dots in their name.

Comment: Oracle has fixed this with 12.1.0.2.  Dots within TNS Entry aliases are now supported.